# how to submit a form on mouse enter using jquery when there are two forms on same page? How to identify these forms separately

Tags: php, jquery

I have two forms on the same page. One is in a modal and another is on the page. Firstly I submitted them on click, but now I want them to be submitted on enter. But when I open the modal above the form then the keypress event will not work. Please give me suggestions on how to identify that on which form the enter key is pressed.

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) { 
        $(this).parents('form').find('.btn-success').trigger('click');  
    }
});
```

This is the code which I am using for submitting a form on enter key pressed. This only works when I open the modal form or page form separately. It doesn't work when I open the modal form above the registration form.

Please suggest something to identify both html forms differently.

Comment: 1. Where is your code. 2. what do you mean "when I open the model". Imagine we are NOT sitting looking over your shoulder. If you use key events in a field, then $(this).closest("form") will give you the parent form

Comment: When I will have two forms and use the function above then this function is not called. It was not tracing the keypress event.

Comment: You can assign IDs to forms and use the id to submit them. @sonamgupta

Comment: I have id's but want to create the common method for triggering click on buttons.Because I have 40-50 forms to submit on enter key press

Comment: So what happens? If the code I posted works then you need to elaborate on the actual code

Comment: My page was big  and is interlinked with different pages.I am trying to put it on code snippit or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```js
$(function () {
    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(this).parents('form').find('.btn-success').trigger('click');
        }
    });
    $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // remove if you want to submit for real
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" class=".btn-success" value="submit"/>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" class=".btn-success" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I have used the code similar to this,  but it was not applying jquery validations and directly go on server side validations .

Comment: It's not going inside the function.And also not identifying keypress event.